# Wait for async function to finish before app.listen in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, cors

I was trying to take whiteList of CORS from the db, but obviously express start listening to the port and setup CORS before I can take values from the database.

That's my code:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs'

//Express and helmet setup
import helmet from 'helmet'
import express from 'express'
const app = express()

app.use(helmet())

//CORS
import { query } from 'graphqurl'

const gqlAPI = process.env.GRAPHQL
const hasuraAdmin = process.env.HASURA_ADMIN
const whiteList = []

const getWhiteList = async function() {
    await query({
        query: `
            query getWhiteList {
                whitelist {
                    origin
                }
            }
        `,
        endpoint: gqlAPI,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'x-hasura-admin-secret': hasuraAdmin
        }
    }).then(res => {
        return res.data.whitelist
    })
    .then(res => {
        res.map(value => (
            whiteList.push(value.origin)
        ))
    })
    .catch(err => { throw new Error(err)})
}
getWhiteList()

import cors from 'cors'
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
          callback(null, true)
        } else {
          callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

//listening
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('whitelist:', whiteList)
    console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
})
```

output is 'whitelist: []'

Is there a method where I can wait for the end of the async function before start listening?

Sorry for my bad English, I hope you get what i'm trying to say.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to actually wrap the `app.listen` method invocation in a `.then` method.

Precisely:

```
getWhiteList().then(() => {
  // [...] More code that might reference the whitelist
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('whitelist:', whiteList)
    console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it into self-invoking async function I think it will work

```
(async () => {

const whiteList = await getWhiteList();

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
          callback(null, true)
        } else {
          callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

//listening
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('whitelist:', whiteList)
    console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
})

})()
```

Comment: Might actually need an `await` while invoking the `getWhitelist()` method. Otherwise, the `whiteList` variable contains a Promise, not the required array.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but:

If your Node version does not support root level await, you can instead do:

```
const configureApplication = async () => {
   await getWhiteList();
   app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('whitelist:', whiteList)
    console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`)
  });
}

configureApplication();
```